# How you do you insert a space above the second page of a table with a repeated header row in a multi-page table?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table that is multiple pages and includes a repeated header row at the top of each page. However, I also need to have a space on the top of each page to add a title (Appendix X Continued).

Usually I'd click on the top left cell and split the table, but the repeated header row won't let me click in that cell. So I'm stuck.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks, 
Danni

Answer (score 1):

Add a blank row to the header and then you can add "Appendix X continued" in the header. You would then need to cover the text on the first page with a white block.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't have a header. The margins must remain empty for binding, but I'm beginning to think this is the only way. Any other suggestions?

Comment: ahhh. gotcha. You mean another header on the table, not the header on the document. Brilliant. Thank you! You might have just saved me a few precious hours of sleep. :)

Comment: @danni that's how I interpreted the answer too (i.e. set two rows of the table as a repeating header) and that's why I up-voted it. It's nice hack indeed.

Comment: ok so now stupid question, but how do you get the "white box" to not repeat in the header on each page as well?

Comment: The white box is anchored on the first page, not in the repeating header.